# Interesting Query in MySQL with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Here is the question:**

Management wants to know which specific aircraft have always been assigned to the same hangar lot (each aircraft is assigned to a lot for only a year and then renewed if requested. But the lot may or may not be the same lot upon renewal; the pk for lots table is registration number and date assigned. List the aircraft registration number, hangar location, hangar capacity. Each aircraft should appear only once in your report.

**Here is lots table:**

> **lot_nbr, hangar_nbr, reg_nbr, date_assigned**
>
> '7706', '1', '505', '2011-07-17'
>   '7707', '1', '505', '2012-07-18'
>     '7708', '1', '505', '2013-12-22'
>     '8801', '2', '101', '2011-01-22'
>     '8802', '2', '101', '2012-01-22'
>     '8803', '2', '303', '2011-01-10'
>     '8803', '2', '202', '2011-04-12'
>     '8803', '2', '202', '2012-04-12'
>     '9902', '3', '303', '2012-01-10'
>     '9904', '3', '404', '2011-01-10'
>     '9905', '3', '404', '2012-01-10'

**Here is hangar table:**

> **hangar_nbr, location, capacity, manager_nbr**
>
> '1', 'South RW', '24', '902'
>   '2', 'North RW', '12', '902'
>   '3', 'West RW', '25', '902'

**Here is aircraft table: (Might be needed)**

> reg_nbr, plane_type, manufacturer, resident, date_service
>   '101', 'SE', 'Prop', 'Lear', '1', '1998-12-01'
>   '202', 'DE Prop', 'Cessna', '1','1999-11-22'
>   '303', 'SE Jet', 'Bombardier', '1', '2000-07-06'
>    '404','ME Jet', 'Lear', '1', '2001-02-24'
>    '505', 'SE Prop', 'Cessna', '0','2003-12-01'
>    '606', 'DE Prop', 'Bombardier', '1', '2004-11-22'
>    '707','SE Jet', 'Lear', '1', '2005-07-06'
>   '808', 'ME Jet', 'Cessna', '0','2005-02-24'
>    '909', 'SE Prop', 'Bombardier', '1', '2002-02-12'

**The query I want (Exactly):**

> **reg_nbr, location, capacity**
>    '202', 'North RW', '12'

**Here is what I tried:**

```
SELECT lots.reg_nbr, location, capacity 
FROM hangar, lots 
WHERE lots.hangar_nbr = hangar.hangar_nbr AND reg_nbr='202'
GROUP BY lots.reg_nbr
```

**My Problem:**

As shown above I wanted to show aircraft with `reg_nbr '202'` in my result because it is the only aircraft that has been allocated the same lot_nbr every time but unfortunately the way I did i.e writing `reg_nbr ='202'` in WHERE clause is not the way query should be done. I want to show how get this results but with a real and legal query. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT reg_nbr
FROM lots
GROUP BY reg_nbr
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lot_nbr) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `reg_nbr` is for the aircraft.  You can get the aircraft with a using a single table, `group by`, and `having` clause:

```
SELECT reg_nbr, hangar_nbr, lot_nbr
FROM lots 
GROUP BY reg_nbr
HAVING MAX(hangar_nbr) = MIN(hangar_nbr) AND
       MAX(lot_nbr) = MIN(lot_nbr)
```

Comment: You rock buddy your query is working and showing only 202 aircraft thanks but only this part is necessary. Thanks a lot :D :D :D life savor 

SELECT reg_nbr, hangar_nbr, lot_nbr
FROM lots 
GROUP BY reg_nbr
HAVING MAX(hangar_nbr) = MIN(hangar_nbr) AND
       MAX(lot_nbr) = MIN(lot_nbr)